# Centering the absolute positioned navigation bar of NivoSlider? (or using the margin: 0 auto trick)?

Tags: css

I added [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) to my Wordpress theme.

In the demo provided with the file the **nivo-ControlNav** has position absolute, and it is moved to the right.

I would like to know if there is a way of centering the **nivo-ControlNav** (and it should even be centered in Internet Explorer)?

**front-page.php**:

```
<div id="feature">
 <div class="container">
  <div id="slider-wrapper">
   <div id="slider">
    <?php // Retrive custom post type with a custom taxonomy assigned to it
     $posts = new WP_Query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)&order=ASC') ?>
    <?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="shadow-slider">
    <!-- Shadow at the bottom of the slider -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #featured -->
```

**stlye.css:**

```
#feature {
 background: #333;
 padding: 30px 0;
 height: 400px;
}
#slider-wrapper {
 float: left;
 height: 500px;
}
#slider {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
#slider {
 position:relative;
 background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#slider img {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 display: none;
}
#slider a {
 border: 0;
 display: block;
}
.nivo-controlNav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 260px;
 bottom: -42px;
 width: 50%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
 display: block;
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 border: 0;
 margin-right: 3px;
 float: left;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
 background-position: 0 -22px;
}
.nivo-directionNav a {
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 border: 0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
 background-position: -30px 0;
 right: 15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
 left: 15px;
}
.nivo-caption {
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Or should I just use the `float: left; margin: 0 auto;` trick?

**EDIT:**

I decided to do this:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 200px;
}

.nivo-controlNav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 200px;
}
```

but the links inside the `nivo-controlNav div` are not centered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you looking for a fail safe method to center the navigation bullets regardless of number of pictures?

Comment: @kjy112 That's right. The number of pictures may vary.

Comment: The way i did it is i manually change the pixel on left in .nivo-controlNav, but you have to change it every time when you add or remove a picture because its a static fix.

Comment: Might this help?        .socialbar {
    position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
    left:20%;
    height: 48px;
    width: 60%;
    background: #282828;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}                                               <div class="socialbar">
Menu
    </div>

Answer (score 4):

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline-block; /* so float:none */
}
```

It will work on all browsers understanding inline-block property.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, and it's relevant for any number of images, the only inconvenient is that you'll have to use jQuery, but I guess that won't be a problem cause Nivo already works with jQuery ^^' ... anyways ...

Based on the earlier posted css codes :

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

I could come up with this javascript code, I'll explain it later :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

    var numberImages = $('#slider img').length;
    var bulletWidth = 22;
    var margin = - ( (numberImages * bulletWidth) / 2 );
    $('.nivo-controlNav').css('margin-left', margin+'px');
});
```

What this basically means is that, instead of giving each slider's controlNav a random margin-left based on the number of images, we'll calculate that, and the way to do that is very simple :

1. We MOVE the left edge of our controlNav to 50% (CSS)

Next we have to know the width of the WHOLE controlNav, which contains bullets of course :

```
`numberImages * bulletWidth`
```

Divide all this by 2, and then remove it from the margin-left, this simply means : move the controlNav by half of its width to the left.

Hope it works for you :)